# Splitting date span into multiple date spans in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have data of Agency records stored like this:

```
Agreement ID   Broker ID      Broker_Eff_Dt    Broker_Term_Dt Broker_Type 
A001              Broker1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    B 
A001              Broker2      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    B
A001              Broker2      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    B 
A001              AGENCY1      01-JUN-2015      31-DEC-9999    A
```

An Agency (Broker_Type = A) is tied to its Brokers (Broker_Type = B) by agreement ID. In this scenario, Agency termination date is open ended (which suggests that it's active) whereas all its Brokers have been terminated.

An Agency can have only at most one broker at once within an agreement.

The requirement is to split the Agency span corresponding to the each of its broker span:

```
Agreement ID   Broker ID      Broker_Eff_Dt    Broker_Term_Dt Broker_Type 
A001              Broker1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    B
A001              Broker2      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    B
A001              Broker2      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    B
A001              AGENCY1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    A
A001              AGENCY1      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    A
A001              AGENCY1      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    A
A001              AGENCY1      01-OCT-2015      31-DEC-9999    A
```

Notice that Agency gets a span to which there is no corresponding broker span.

It's not always that an Agency's span will exceed those of its brokers. If they coincide, Number of Agency spans should be same as those of Brokers'. 
For example:

```
Agreement ID   Broker ID      Broker_Eff_Dt    Broker_Term_Dt Broker_Type 
A001              AGENCY1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    B
A001              AGENCY2      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    B
A001              AGENCY3      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    B
A001              Broker1      01-JUN-2015      30-SEP-2015    A
```

after run:

```
Agreement ID   Broker ID      Broker_Eff_Dt    Broker_Term_Dt Broker_Type 
A001              Broker1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    B
A001              Broker2      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    B
A001              Broker2      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    B
A001              AGENCY1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    A
A001              AGENCY1      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    A
A001              AGENCY1      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    A
```

If the last broker has a greater span than its Agency that similar thing should happen to Broker span. For example:

```
Agreement ID   Broker ID      Broker_Eff_Dt    Broker_Term_Dt Broker_Type 
A001              AGENCY1      01-JUN-2015      13-JUN-2015    B
A001              AGENCY2      14-JUN-2015      21-AUG-2015    B
A001              AGENCY3      22-AUG-2015      30-SEP-2015    B
A001              Broker1      01-JUN-2015      31-DEC-9999    A
```

In this case Broker's term should be split corresponding to its Agency.

Database is Oracle 11g.

Can we achieve it in SQL (without using any cursor) such as using CONNECT BY?

Thanks

Comment: Could there be a gap between two brokers?  Could the span between two brokers overlap?

Comment: Hi Gordon - No there can not be any gap between two brokers (they'll be always continuous) and the spans between two brokers can't overlap.